# Installing custom ROM in Android studio AVD

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, android-emulator

Is there any way for installing a custom ROM in Android studio Android emulator?
I have Resurrection Remix Naught 7.1 ROM downloaded on my computer.
In Android studio, I didn't found any option for choosing downloaded ROMs.
Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very unlikely that regular custom ROMs will work in the emulator:

For the android emulator special device drivers like display and other fake drivers/services (e.g. for telephone, GPS with is usable but there is no GPS chip) are needed. Regular custom ROMS don't contain those drivers and therefore can't be loaded in the emulator.

If you want an adapted ROM for the emulator you need an image that bases on the AOSP emulator image.

Comment: Even I have that kind of ROM, how do I install it on Android studio? I didn't found any button saying "install ROM from storage". Is there any ?

Comment: If you have a ROM that is prepared for the emulator I would assume that the creator includes an AVD file to run in the emulator. Otherwise if i remember right the AVD files is an INI file which links the different system image files together. It should be possible to create a standard emulator and then replace the different image files with those from your ROM.